# program does not output to console

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

I made a program that when you input your score and the max potential score, the percentage will be calculated - based on the percentage you will assigned a grade which will be logged to the console. I was able to make it work before but now it doesn't and i can't seem to find the issue, could you please tell me what im doing wrong and how i can fix it.

Also currently after inputting the score and max potential score, the user has to click anywhere on the screen due to the "change" event listener. Is there a way i can input the data but after pressing a submit button, only then the grade will be calculated (similar to ordinary websites)- instead of clicking anywhere.

Thank you

```js
   const text = function() {
        const max = document.getElementById("totalInput")
        const score = document.getElementById("totalScore")

        max.addEventListener("change", function(inputMax) {
           const result1 = inputMax.target.value
            score.addEventListener("change", function(inputScore) {
               const result2 = inputScore.target.value
                const percentage = result2 / result1
                if (percentage >= 80 && percentage <= 100) {
                    console.log(`you recieved an A - ${percentage}`);
                } else if (percentage >= 70 && percentage <= 79) {
                    console.log(`you recieved an B - ${percentage}`);
                } else if (percentage >= 50 && percentage <= 69) {
                    console.log(`you recieved an C - ${percentage}`);
                } else if (percentage >= 40 && percentage <= 49) {
                    console.log(`you recieved an D - ${percentage}`);
                } 
            })
        })
    }

    text()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Grade Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
    <h3>Please Enter your score:</h3>
    <input id="totalInput" type="text" placeholder="Max possible score">
    <input id="totalScore" type="text" placeholder="Score">
    <div id="outputresults">
        
    </div>
    <H3>Click anywhere on the screen after entering score to recieve result!</H3>
    <script src="grade.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is bad practice to bind an event listener inside an event listener. every time you change max, it adds another event.

Comment: You're expecting `percentage` to be a whole number - can you elaborate on that? You probably mean to compare to their decimal equivalent. A percentage between 80% and 100% would actually need to be compared to `0.8` and `1.0`, etc... did you mean to multiply `percentage` to get it to this form?

Comment: Learn to debug `const percentage = result2 / result1;
console.log(percentage)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without straying too far from your original code I've adjusted a few things to get your console logging again. I also added a button to calculate your logic instead of using the coupled `onchange` events you were using on each input to trigger your function.

Additionally, I decided to exclude your wrapping `text()` function because it is not necessary.

The strange part is that your logic is not accounting for all outcomes and does not have a final `else` statement to handle cases outside of the conditions you've set.

See the snippet below, some light comments included for the added code.

```js
const max = document.getElementById("totalInput")
const score = document.getElementById("totalScore")
//declare btn as variable
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")

//when button is clicked run the function
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const result1 = max.value
  const result2 = score.value
  const percentage = result2 / result1
  if (percentage >= 0.80 && percentage <= 1) {
    console.log(`you recieved an A - ${percentage}`);
  } else if (percentage >= 0.70 && percentage <= 0.79) {
    console.log(`you recieved an B - ${percentage}`);
  } else if (percentage >= 0.50 && percentage <= 0.69) {
    console.log(`you recieved an C - ${percentage}`);
  } else if (percentage >= 0.40 && percentage <= 0.49) {
    console.log(`you recieved an D - ${percentage}`);
  }
  //there should probably be a final else statement down here to handle cases outside of your declared logic above
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Grade Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
  <h3>Please Enter your score:</h3>
  <input id="totalInput" type="text" placeholder="Max possible score">
  <input id="totalScore" type="text" placeholder="Score">
  <!--Button added to calculate score-->
  <button id="btn">Calculate</button>
  <div id="outputresults">

  </div>
  <H3>Click button after entering score to recieve result!</H3>
  <script src="grade.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```